# Indenting text-block with python Rich library

Tags: python, formatting, rich

I'm trying to print a formatted block of markdown text to the terminal using rich.console.print(Markdown(text)) from the Rich library. However, I would like to have this block of text be indented with a tab. Normally I'd use the textwrap module for that, but when using it, rich.Markdown() will interpret it as a code-block, and thus not applying any formatting to the markdown besides giving it a different background.

Example of using textwrap:
[textwrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02mC7.png)

Example of not using textwrap:
[no textwrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5svym.png)

My Python code:

```py
    pretty_console.console.print("[u bright_blue]All series:[/]")
    for e in display_data:
        pretty_console.console.print(
            f"{e['id'].ljust(max_series_id_length)}: "
            f"[bold]{e['name'].ljust(max_series_name_length)}[/]\n"
        )
        if e['description']:
            text = e['description']
            markdown_text = Markdown(text)
            pretty_console.console.print(markdown_text)
```

Excuse the Dutch in the pictures, but the language won't really matter in this case.

Does anyone know how to print Rich formatted text with an indent that works too when (soft-) wrapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Padding` to indent output:

```py
from rich.console import Console
from rich.padding import Padding

console = Console()
console.print(Padding("my text", pad=(0, 0, 0, 4))) # Indent by 4 spaces.
```